# html in string remove inside of style - regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**NOTE:**
This is a string and not an actual DOM element

I have this string

```
<p><span contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false" data-role="img-crop"><img alt="" data-role="img-resizable" data-x="0" data-y="0" draggable="false" height="146" src="temporary/e78f4ed1-9f8b-443b-b6b0-678c6dad97bd.jpg"  width="293" /></span></span> &lt;span&gt;small&lt;/span&gt;<span contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false" data-role="img-crop"><img alt="" data-role="img-resizable" data-x="0" data-y="0" draggable="false" height="208" src="temporary/eeaf1f44-5c17-48f6-9204-210b64f79f98.jpg" style="cursor: pointer" width="554" /></span></span> </p><p>dsadsadas<br /></p>
```

and I want to remove the content of `style` to be like this `style=""` but i dont know how using regex. Note only regex and not using `removeAttr()` of jquery

I already tried this regex `/style="[^"]*/g` but it removes the style string which is what i dont want to since i am comparing it to the original content that has an empty style

Please help

Comment: A DOM element never has an empty `style` attribute, if it is made empty, it is removed.

Comment: @Teemu I never said it is a DOM element, its a string which has HTML content. adding a NOTE for you to understand

Comment: "_comparing it to the original content_" The original content is not in the DOM?

Comment: @Teemu it is not a DOM.

Comment: That's awful, make a temporal element and use a HTML parser to manipulate a HTMLString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just use `replace` with a capturing group:

```
str = str.replace(/(style=")(?:[^"]*)(")/g, "$1$2");
```

Comment: nice. this is what I am looking